# How to return date from Rest API eg. 1185746400000 OR Custom format like "2021.12.31 22:00:00"?

Tags: java, rest, date, web-services

What is correct way of returning date from Rest API

This

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
protected Date changeDate;
validFrom": "2021.12.31 22:00:00", (Any random format using Date or XmlGregorianCalendar etc. or specific format)
```

Or

```
private Date startDateConcern;
"startDateConcern": 1185746400000
```

Preparing a Masterdata API so finding this information. Will that "1185746400000" confusing for my customers?

Comment: Both of the `Date` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

Comment: Return [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format with UTC offset. Use Offset `Z` (zero) if there isn’t a particular reason for something else. You can generate it easily from an `Instant` with jackson-modules-java-8. 1185746400000 confuses me, what is it? A date in late July 2007?